# Use a RequiredFieldValidator in my webform

Tags: c#, database, webforms, requiredfieldvalidator

I used a requiredfieldvalidator in my webform application.
I want when a person fills all of textboxes in my form and then press "OK" button, the data save to database. But if any textboxes didn't fill, requiredfieldvalidator show a message and data doesn't save to database.
Now I can use requiredfieldvalidator and it messages me when textboxes didn't fill. But other data in my textboxes will save to my database.
Please help me that in this condition, the data doesn't save to database.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate and show us some of your code? Each RequiredFieldValidator works on one texbox only. So if you have more than one textbox you will need to have a required field validator for each one of them.

Comment: I think, you need to provide more details! specifically about the code you have written so far! Then SO users will be in a better position to help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Validate your data on the server side (e.g. on the button click) before committing data to the database. Remember that if, for example, the user has disabled javascript in the browser, the validators will not work.

On the client side, you can use the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx) property.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can do a [Page.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx) before trying to save to the database.
2. If you have used [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx), make sure that you have properly used the validation groups for all the components.

It would be better to see some code though.